# How to use onConfigurationChanged in case of Gallery intent?

Tags: android, android-gallery

In my application I am giving the user an option to choose a picture from gallery or click it from a camera, using the inbuilt camera and gallery features and setting intents for the same. Somehow on Orientation change I lose the data passed from these intents. After looking up I came to know that orientation change causes activity to redraw and re-initialize. Now I want to use Bundle and OnConfigurationChange and save my extras. I am clueless about how to achieve it, a detailed answer could be helpful.  Below is my code:

```
if(i==0){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); 
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if( requestCode == 1337 && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if (extras != null){
            TitmapFactory.Options options = new TitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            thumbnail = (Titmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            // imgview.setImageTitmap(thumbnail);
            image(thumbnail);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(CreateProfile.this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     
    }
}






     if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){

         Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));



            image(thumbnail);

     }
```

Comment: What does the <activity> tag for this activity look like in the mainfest?

Comment: I had modified it to android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  
But this either does not seem to work. It does work fine with some mobile phones like DELL XCD35 and HTC Wildfire S but it fails on Samsung devices.

Comment: +1 For the question. Hmm... Interesting.

Comment: I am installing device drivers for HTC and Samsung, will post the logcat.

Comment: On installing the drivers I came to know that the error was alltogether different, it was a VM Budget issue and I have resolved it. Thank you :)